# How to reduce/free memory when using xarray datasets?

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

This is the output of the memory profiler of a function in my code, using xarray (v.0.16.1)  datasets:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   139   94.195 MiB   94.195 MiB   @profile
   140                             def getMaps(ncfile):
   141  335.914 MiB  241.719 MiB       myCMEMSdata = xr.open_dataset(ncfile).resample(time='3H').reduce(np.mean)
   142                             
   143  335.945 MiB    0.031 MiB       plt.figure(figsize=(20.48, 10.24))
   144                             
   145                                 # projection, lat/lon extents and resolution of polygons to draw
   146                                 # resolutions: c - crude, l - low, i - intermediate, h - high, f - full
   147  336.809 MiB    0.863 MiB       map = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlon=-10.,
   148  335.945 MiB    0.000 MiB                     llcrnrlat=30., urcrnrlon=36.5, urcrnrlat=46.)
   149                             
   150                             
   151  339.773 MiB    2.965 MiB       X, Y = np.meshgrid(myCMEMSdata.longitude.values,
   152  336.809 MiB    0.000 MiB                          myCMEMSdata.latitude.values)
   153  348.023 MiB    8.250 MiB       x, y = map(X, Y)
   154                             
   155                                 # reduce arrows density (1 out of 15)
   156  348.023 MiB    0.000 MiB       yy = np.arange(0, y.shape[0], 15)
   157  348.023 MiB    0.000 MiB       xx = np.arange(0, x.shape[1], 15)
   158  348.023 MiB    0.000 MiB       points = np.meshgrid(yy,xx)
   159                             
   160                                 #cycle time to save maps
   161  348.023 MiB    0.000 MiB       i=0
   162  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB       while i < myCMEMSdata.time.values.size:
   163  742.566 MiB  305.996 MiB           map.shadedrelief(scale=0.65)
   164                                     #waves height
   165  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           waveH = myCMEMSdata.VHM0.values[i, :, :]
   166  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
   167  742.566 MiB    0.043 MiB           map.pcolormesh(x, y, waveH, cmap=my_cmap, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=0.07, vmax=4.,clip=True))
   168                                     # waves direction
   169  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           wDir = myCMEMSdata.VMDR.values[i, :, :]
   170  742.566 MiB    0.242 MiB           map.quiver(x[tuple(points)],y[tuple(points)],np.cos(np.deg2rad(270-wDir[tuple(points)])),np.sin(np.deg2rad(270-wDir[tuple(points)])),
   171  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB               edgecolor='lightgray', minshaft=4,  width=0.007, headwidth=3., headlength=4., linewidth=.5)
   172                                     # save plot
   173  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           filename = pd.to_datetime(myCMEMSdata.time[i].values).strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H")
   174  742.566 MiB    0.086 MiB           plt.show()
   175  742.566 MiB   39.406 MiB           plt.savefig(TEMPDIR+filename+".jpg", quality=75)
   176  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           plt.clf()
   177  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           del wDir
   178  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           del waveH
   179  742.566 MiB    0.000 MiB           i += 1
   180                             
   181                                 #out of loop
   182  581.840 MiB    0.000 MiB       plt.close("all")
   183  581.840 MiB    0.000 MiB       myCMEMSdata.close()
   184  441.961 MiB    0.000 MiB       del myCMEMSdata
```

As you can see the allocated memory is not freed up, and after many runs of the program, it simply fails ("Killed") for low memory.

How can I free the memory allocated by the dataset? I am using either dataset.close() and deleting the variable, with no success.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `plt` code? I think that's the most likely place to be holding onto local references from the global context

Comment: @Maximilian, it looks like plt code is consuming very low memory... I see that the most consuming are the dataset open and the map shade. But how could I release them better than deleting the associated variables?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `plt` code? Even if it's causing memory increase, it could be holding references such that objects aren't being freed

Comment: I can't just remove the plt code. It is spread all over that  function... I am close all plt with plt.close("all)

Comment: I'm suggesting temporarily removing the `plt` code to see the impact on memory usage. Or if you have other ideas to make the problem smaller — please go ahead.